# Recursive and Pivot query not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which stores Geo Hierarchy in a parent and child relationship

Sample Data for the Geo Table is

```
 ChildName      ChildCode   ParentName     ParentCode ChildLevelName
 A9             DG1-100     NULL            NULL         Geography_Display_Big_Area
 United States  DG2-200     A9              DG1-100      Geography_Display_Area
 United States  DG3-300     United States   DG2-200      Geography_Display_Region
 United States  LC          United States   DG3-300      Geography_Display_Sub_Region
 United States  JW          United States   LC           Geography_Display_SalesLocation
```

I want the result to be

```
Display_Big_Area    Display_Area    Display_Region  Display_Sub_Region  Display_SalesLocation
 A9                 United States   United States   United States       United States
```

I tried to use PIVOT

```
SELECT ChildName,
[Geography_Display_Area], [Geography_Display_Big_Area],
 [Geography_Display_Region], [Geography_Display_SalesLocation],
 [Geography_Display_Sub_Region]
 from
(
 SELECT childname,parentCode, parentname,childlevelname
 from Table
) as st
 pivot
(
 max(ParentName)
FOR childlevelname in ([Geography_Display_Area],
   [Geography_Display_Big_Area], [Geography_Display_Region],
   [Geography_Display_SalesLocation], [Geography_Display_Sub_Region])
 ) as pivottable
```

`Result`

```
  childname   Geography_Display_Area    Geography_Display_Big_Area  Geography_Display_Region    Geography_Display_SalesLocation Geography_Display_Sub_Region
   United States          A9                    NULL                        United States                     United States                     United States
```

But the hierarchy seems to get re-arranged

Can some one please help me out with the query.

Comment: If you want this result? why you're  selecting in sourse table 3 fields and use max(parentName). You can get this result simple query:SELECT 
[Geography_Display_Area], [Geography_Display_Big_Area],
 [Geography_Display_Region], [Geography_Display_SalesLocation],
 [Geography_Display_Sub_Region]
 from
(
 SELECT childname,childlevelname
 from TestTable
) as st
 pivot
(
 max(childname)
FOR childlevelname in ([Geography_Display_Area],
   [Geography_Display_Big_Area], [Geography_Display_Region],
   [Geography_Display_SalesLocation], [Geography_Display_Sub_Region])
 ) as pivottable

Comment: With the above query only 1 row will be extracted

Comment: But in your result example there is only one row

Comment: That was a sample data. I have approx. 400  countries for which  hierarchies have been defined.

Comment: You need to build group field. If table have only 5 fixed different childlevel, you can do this, just use left join(self) begining with Geography_Display_SalesLocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use left join (self) by child and parent node. If length always the same you can use this query

```
    SELECT 
   tt.ChildName Geography_Display_SalesLocation,
   tt2.ChildName [Geography_Display_Sub_Region],
   tt3.ChildName [Geography_Display_Region],
   tt4.ChildName [Geography_Display_Area],
   tt5.ChildName [Geography_Display_Big_Area]
 FROM   
   TestTable tt
     LEFT JOIN TestTable tt2
       ON tt.ParentCode = tt2.ChildCode
     LEFT JOIN TestTable tt3
       ON tt2.ParentCode = tt3.ChildCode
     LEFT JOIN TestTable tt4
       ON tt3.ParentCode = tt4.ChildCode
     LEFT JOIN TestTable tt5
       ON tt4.ParentCode = tt5.ChildCode
 WHERE  
   tt.ChildLevelName = 'Geography_Display_SalesLocation'
```

You haven't got group field for using PIVOT